# Fater update pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame named `df` has column `GENDER`, `AGE` and `ID` and others columns, and there is another DataFrame named `df_2` which has only 3 columns `GENDER`, `AGE` and `ID` too. I want to update the value of `GENDER` and `AGE` in `df` with values from `df_2`.

So my ideas is

```
df_id = df.ID.tolist()
df_2_id = df_2.ID.tolist()

df = df.set_index('ID')
df_2 = df_2.set_index('ID')

# all the ids in df_2_id are in df_id
for id in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(df_2_id):
    df.loc[id, 'GENDER'] = df_2.loc[id, 'GENDER']
    df.loc[id, 'AGE'] = df_2.loc[id, 'AGE']
```

However, the for loop only has 17.2 iterations per seconds, and it around takes 2 hours to update the data. How can I make it faster?

Comment: not using pandas would make it faster

Comment: doesn't `df['GENDER'] = df_2['GENDER']` then `df['AGE'] = df_2['AGE']` work? why are you using a for-loop over `ID`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, since the `df` and `df_2` have different shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) of indices and then set values:

```
idx = df.index.intersection(df_2.index)
df.loc[idx, 'GENDER'] = df_2['GENDER']
df.loc[idx, 'AGE'] = df_2['AGE']
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together and remove duplicates, keep last value:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_2])
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Similar solution:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_2]).reset_index().drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('abcdef'),
                   'AGE':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'GENDER':list('aaabbb')})

#print (df)


df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('def'),
                   'AGE':[90,20,40],
                   'GENDER':list('eee')})

#print (df_2)

df = df.set_index('ID')
df_2 = df_2.set_index('ID')

idx = df.index.intersection(df_2.index)
df.loc[idx, 'GENDER'] = df_2['GENDER']
df.loc[idx, 'AGE'] = df_2['AGE']

print (df)
    AGE GENDER
ID            
a     5      a
b     3      a
c     6      a
d    90      e
e    20      e
f    40      e
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, the `df` has other columns except `GENDER`, `AGE` and `ID`. Does your method still work?

Comment: And `df_2` not? it have only 3 columns?

Comment: `df_2` only has 3 columns

Comment: I test it with `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('abcdef'),
                   'AGE':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'GENDER':list('aaabbb'),
                   'col1':list('oookkk')})` and first solution working nice.

Comment: Thank you, you are really a Pandas expert! Now it updates the value within seconds, around 9000 times faster!

Comment: @AlexanderYau - In my opinion there is many experts in SO ;) Thank you.